# I'm using the same js file for two different types of images named as colored and type but it isn't working for me

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that I'm using the same js file with different name. The function of both files is the same. The first js file is sliding the 5 images (black and white) and the other js is sliding only two images (colored) on different links on the same page.
But both are not working properly means if one slider for black and white image is working then the other one for colored images is not working. please help me.

Js is referenced in a script file named as: coverflow-color.js

```
var min = 1; //minimum number of image
var max = 3; //maximum number of images
var current = 2; //image number that is at the center of the coverflow
var currPos = 0; //custom attribute that stores current TranslateX position of each image
var newPos = 0; //custom attribute that stores new TranslateX position of each image, i.e after movement
var currAngle = 0; //custom attribute that stores current RotationY angle of each image
var newAngle = 0; //custom attribute that stores new RotationY angle of each image
var gap = 75;
var clickedIndex = 0; //index of the image tapped
var isMouseDown = false; //has the user interacted
var swipeStartX = 0;
var swipeDistanceX = 0;
var diff = 0;
var imageTapStartX = 0;
var imageTapEndX = 0;
var imageTapDistanceX= 0;
var coverFlowContainerElement = null;
var thresholdDistanceSingleSlide = 0; //this measures the distance

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    /* Hide the browser address bar. This will give a native feel to the app */
    setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 20);

    /* Get the pointer to the coverflow holder */
    coverFlowContainerElement = document.getElementById("coverflow");
    moveImagesFromRight();  //help comments are there in the function definition
    addEventsToImageHolders(); //help comments are there in the function definition
    addEventToCoverflowHolder(); //help comments are there in the function definition

    thresholdDistanceSingleSlide = parseInt(300 / max);
    disablePageScroll();  //help comments are there in the function definition
},false);

/*
    Give the initial thrust to the slides from the right. I have just given it an effect of the images being
    thrown into the center from the right.
*/
function moveImagesFromRight()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("fig1").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-150px) rotateY(30deg)";
      document.getElementById("fig2").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(200px)";
      document.getElementById("fig3").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(150px) rotateY(-30deg)";
    }, 150);
}

/* Register touch event listener to the image holders i.e the <div> holding each images */
function addEventsToImageHolders()
{
    var imageHolders = coverFlowContainerElement.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0;i<imageHolders.length;i++)
    {
        //console.log(imageHolders[i]);
        imageHolders[i].addEventListener("touchstart",handleImageTapStart,false);
        imageHolders[i].addEventListener("touchend",handleImageTapEnd,false);
    }
}

/*
    Add touch events to the <div id='coverflow' /> container. So the container registers the finger movements
    and acts accordingly
*/
function addEventToCoverflowHolder()
{
    coverFlowContainerElement.addEventListener("touchstart", handleFingerSwipeStart, false);
    coverFlowContainerElement.addEventListener("touchmove", handleFingerSwipeMove, false);
    coverFlowContainerElement.addEventListener("touchend", handleFingerSwipeEnd, false);
}

/* The default behavior of the browser is to scroll when you swipe. This line is to prevent scrolling */
function disablePageScroll() {
  document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }
}

/* Events for the <div id='coverflow'></div> holder */
function handleFingerSwipeStart(event) {
  isMouseDown = true;
  swipeStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  event.preventDefault();
}
function handleFingerSwipeMove(event) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
      swipeDistanceX = parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].pageX - swipeStartX);//

      var netDistance = Math.abs(swipeDistanceX);
      //console.log("Move: " + swipeDistanceX + " Net distance: " + netDistance); //changedTouches[0].
      if (netDistance >= thresholdDistanceSingleSlide) {
          //console.log(thresholdDistanceSingleSlide + " covered");
          if (swipeDistanceX < 0) {
              right();
              swipeStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
          }
          else {
              left();
              swipeStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
          }
      }
  }
}
function handleFingerSwipeEnd(event) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
      isMouseDown = false;
      swipeStartX = 0;
  }
}

/*
    Events for the <div id="fig"></div> elements where fig starts from 1 to 7. The images are
    inside these element
*/
function handleImageTapStart(event) {
    imageTapStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
}
function handleImageTapEnd(event) {
    imageTapEndX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    imageTapDistanceX = imageTapEndX - imageTapStartX;
    var targetObj = event.currentTarget;
    if (imageTapDistanceX == 0) {
      clickedIndex = parseInt(targetObj.id.slice(3, 4));
      if (clickedIndex > current) {
          //move right to the clicked index
          diff = clickedIndex - current;
          for (var i = 1; i <= diff; i++) {
              right();
          }
      }
      else if (clickedIndex < current) {
          //move left to the clicked index
          diff = (current - clickedIndex);
          for (var i = 1; i <= diff; i++) {
              left();
          }
      }
      else {
          //same element is clicked....do nothing
          //alert(clickedIndex);
          document.getElementById("coverflow").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("fig"+clickedIndex+"_content").style.display="block";
      }
    }
}

/* Functions - left() & right() for actually moving the images when user interacts*/
/* Move an image from L -> R i.e you are swiping from L->R across the screen */
function left() {
  if (current > min) {
      current--;

      for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
          currPos = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("cp");
          currAngle = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("a");
          if (currPos == "-150" || currPos == "0") {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap * 2) * (1);
              if (currPos == "0") {
                  newAngle = -30;
              }
              else if (currPos = "-150") {
                  newAngle = 0;
              }
              else {
              }
          }
          else {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap) * (1);
              newAngle = parseInt(currAngle);
          }
          if (i == current) {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg) translateZ(200px)";
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg)";
          }
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("cp", newPos);
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("a", newAngle);
      }
  }
}
/* Move an image from R -> L i.e you are swiping from R->L across the screen */
function right() {
  if (current < max) {
      current++;

      for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
          currPos = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("cp");
          currAngle = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("a");
          if (currPos == "150" || currPos == "0") {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap * 2) * (-1);
              if (currPos == "0") {
                  newAngle = 30;
              }
              else if (currPos = "150") {
                  newAngle = 0;
              }
              else {
              }
          }
          else {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap) * (-1);
              newAngle = parseInt(currAngle);
          }
          if (i == current) {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg) translateZ(200px)";
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg)";
          }
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("cp", newPos);
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("a", newAngle);
      }
  }
}
```

and the other Js is referenced in a script file named as: coverflow-type.js

```
var min = 1; //minimum number of image
var max = 5; //maximum number of images
var current = 3; //image number that is at the center of the coverflow
var currPos = 0; //custom attribute that stores current TranslateX position of each image
var newPos = 0; //custom attribute that stores new TranslateX position of each image, i.e after movement
var currAngle = 0; //custom attribute that stores current RotationY angle of each image
var newAngle = 0; //custom attribute that stores new RotationY angle of each image
var gap = 75;
var clickedIndex = 0; //index of the image tapped
var isMouseDown = false; //has the user interacted
var swipeStartX = 0;
var swipeDistanceX = 0;
var diff = 0;
var imageTapStartX = 0;
var imageTapEndX = 0;
var imageTapDistanceX= 0;
var coverFlowContainerElement = null;
var thresholdDistanceSingleSlide = 0; //this measures the distance

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    /* Hide the browser address bar. This will give a native feel to the app */
    setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 20);

    /* Get the pointer to the coverflow holder */
    coverFlowContainerElement = document.getElementById("coverflow");
    moveImagesFromRight();  //help comments are there in the function definition
    addEventsToImageHolders(); //help comments are there in the function definition
    addEventToCoverflowHolder(); //help comments are there in the function definition

    thresholdDistanceSingleSlide = parseInt(300 / max);
    disablePageScroll();  //help comments are there in the function definition
},false);

/*
    Give the initial thrust to the slides from the right. I have just given it an effect of the images being
    thrown into the center from the right.
*/
function moveImagesFromRight()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("fig1").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-225px) rotateY(30deg)";
      document.getElementById("fig2").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-150px) rotateY(30deg)";
      document.getElementById("fig3").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(200px)";
      document.getElementById("fig4").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(150px) rotateY(-30deg)";
      document.getElementById("fig5").style.webkitTransform = "translateX(225px) rotateY(-30deg)";
    }, 150);
}

/* Register touch event listener to the image holders i.e the <div> holding each images */
function addEventsToImageHolders()
{
    var imageHolders = coverFlowContainerElement.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0;i<imageHolders.length;i++)
    {
        //console.log(imageHolders[i]);
        imageHolders[i].addEventListener("touchstart",handleImageTapStart,false);
        imageHolders[i].addEventListener("touchend",handleImageTapEnd,false);
    }
}

/*
    Add touch events to the <div id='coverflow' /> container. So the container registers the finger movements
    and acts accordingly
*/
function addEventToCoverflowHolder()
{
    coverFlowContainerElement.addEventListener("touchstart", handleFingerSwipeStart, false);
    coverFlowContainerElement.addEventListener("touchmove", handleFingerSwipeMove, false);
    coverFlowContainerElement.addEventListener("touchend", handleFingerSwipeEnd, false);
}

/* The default behavior of the browser is to scroll when you swipe. This line is to prevent scrolling */
function disablePageScroll() {
  document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }
}

/* Events for the <div id='coverflow'></div> holder */
function handleFingerSwipeStart(event) {
  isMouseDown = true;
  swipeStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  event.preventDefault();
}
function handleFingerSwipeMove(event) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
      swipeDistanceX = parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].pageX - swipeStartX);//

      var netDistance = Math.abs(swipeDistanceX);
      //console.log("Move: " + swipeDistanceX + " Net distance: " + netDistance); //changedTouches[0].
      if (netDistance >= thresholdDistanceSingleSlide) {
          //console.log(thresholdDistanceSingleSlide + " covered");
          if (swipeDistanceX < 0) {
              right();
              swipeStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
          }
          else {
              left();
              swipeStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
          }
      }
  }
}
function handleFingerSwipeEnd(event) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
      isMouseDown = false;
      swipeStartX = 0;
  }
}

/*
    Events for the <div id="fig"></div> elements where fig starts from 1 to 7. The images are
    inside these element
*/
function handleImageTapStart(event) {
    imageTapStartX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
}
function handleImageTapEnd(event) {
    imageTapEndX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    imageTapDistanceX = imageTapEndX - imageTapStartX;
    var targetObj = event.currentTarget;
    if (imageTapDistanceX == 0) {
      clickedIndex = parseInt(targetObj.id.slice(3, 4));
      if (clickedIndex > current) {
          //move right to the clicked index
          diff = clickedIndex - current;
          for (var i = 1; i <= diff; i++) {
              right();
          }
      }
      else if (clickedIndex < current) {
          //move left to the clicked index
          diff = (current - clickedIndex);
          for (var i = 1; i <= diff; i++) {
              left();
          }
      }
      else {
          //same element is clicked....do nothing
         // alert(clickedIndex);
          console.log(targetObj);
          var thumbfile=targetObj.getAttribute("rel");
          document.getElementById("coverflow").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("content").style.display="block";
            var thumbList=show(thumbfile);
            document.getElementById("Tlist").innerHTML=thumbList;
            window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'),{ 
            callback: function(e, pos) {
            var i = bullets.length;
            while (i--) {
            bullets[i].className = '';
            }
            bullets[pos].className = 'on';
            }
            }),
            bullets = document.getElementById('position').getElementsByTagName('span');
      }
    }
}

/* Functions - left() & right() for actually moving the images when user interacts*/
/* Move an image from L -> R i.e you are swiping from L->R across the screen */
function left() {
  if (current > min) {
      current--;

      for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
          currPos = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("cp");
          currAngle = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("a");
          if (currPos == "-150" || currPos == "0") {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap * 2) * (1);
              if (currPos == "0") {
                  newAngle = -30;
              }
              else if (currPos = "-150") {
                  newAngle = 0;
              }
              else {
              }
          }
          else {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap) * (1);
              newAngle = parseInt(currAngle);
          }
          if (i == current) {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg) translateZ(200px)";
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg)";
          }
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("cp", newPos);
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("a", newAngle);
      }
  }
}
/* Move an image from R -> L i.e you are swiping from R->L across the screen */
function right() {
  if (current < max) {
      current++;

      for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
          currPos = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("cp");
          currAngle = document.getElementById("fig" + i).getAttribute("a");
          if (currPos == "150" || currPos == "0") {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap * 2) * (-1);
              if (currPos == "0") {
                  newAngle = 30;
              }
              else if (currPos = "150") {
                  newAngle = 0;
              }
              else {
              }
          }
          else {
              newPos = parseInt(currPos) + (gap) * (-1);
              newAngle = parseInt(currAngle);
          }
          if (i == current) {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg) translateZ(200px)";
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById("fig" + i).style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + newPos + "px) rotateY(" + newAngle + "deg)";
          }
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("cp", newPos);
          document.getElementById("fig" + i).setAttribute("a", newAngle);
      }
  }
}





// show thumbnails functions

//function show(dname){ 
//  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
//      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();     
//      }
//      else{
//      xhttp=new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);  
//        } 
//     xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);     
//     xhttp.send();       
//     var xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
//     var thumblist=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset");
//    //str=""; 
//    str="<li>";
//    var image= new Array();    
//    for(i=0, tc=1; i<thumblist.length;i++){
//        var x=thumblist[i].childNodes;
//         for(j=0,index=0; j<x.length;j++){
//             if(x[j].nodeType==1){
//                image[index]=(x[j].firstChild.nodeValue);
//                 index++;
//                 }
//               x[j]=x[j].nextSibling;             
//            }
//            str+='<div><a href="'+image[2]+'"><img src="'+image[0]+'"></a><span>'+image[1]+'</span></div>';
//            // tc<thumblist.length check for the last node                          
//             if(tc%6==0&& tc<thumblist.length){
//                  str+="</li><li>";   
//               } 
//          tc++;                  
//        // str+='<div class="thumbwrapper"><img src="'+image[0]+'">'+image[1]+'</div>'; 
//        //str+='<li><img src="'+image[0]+'"><span>'+image[1]+'</span></li>';                    
//        }
//      str+="</li>";  
//   //alert(str);
//   console.log(str);     
//   return str;       
//  }


  function show(dname){ 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();     
        }
      else{
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);  
          } 
       xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);     
       xhttp.send();       
       var xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
       var thumblist=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset");
      //str=""; 
      str="<li>";
      var image= new Array();    
      for(i=0, tc=1; i<thumblist.length;i++){
          // getting the attribute node of every assets
              var thumb=thumblist[i].attributes;
              str+='<div><a href="'+thumb.getNamedItem("url").nodeValue+'"><img src="'+thumb.getNamedItem("thumbnail").nodeValue+'"></a><span>'+thumb.getNamedItem("title").nodeValue+'</span></div>';
              // (tc<thumblist.length) check for the last node                        
               if(tc%6==0&& tc<thumblist.length){
                    str+="</li><li>";   
                 } 
            tc++;                                     
          }
        str+="</li>";  
     //alert(str);
     console.log(str);     
     return str;       
  }
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>GRAAVAA HTML5</title>

<link href="css/bgLandscape.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bgLandscape.css" media="screen and (device-width:768px) and (orientation:landscape) or (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css" />

<link href="css/coverflow.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="bg">
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
</ul>

<div id="formContainer" class="formContainer">
            <form id="login" method="post" action="index.html" class="login">
                 <span id="msg" class="error"></span>
<!--                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address" class="stored" required="required" placeholder="admin@mail.com"/>-->
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="email" style="top:176px;" />
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Full Name" class="stored"/>
                <!--<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Skip" />-->
                <input type="button" name="skip" id="skip" value="Skip" class="skip" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="submit" />
    </form>

  </div>



<!-- Collection By Type -->

<div id="wrapperType" class="collectionTypeWrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="coverflow">
          <div id="fig1" cp="-225" a="30" rel="xml/granite.xml"><img src="collectionType/granite.jpg" /></div>
          <div id="fig2" cp="-150" a="30" rel="xml/marble.xml"><img src="collectionType/marble.jpg" /></div>
          <div id="fig3" cp="0" a="0" rel="xml/onyx.xml"><img src="collectionType/onyx.jpg" /></div>
          <div id="fig4" cp="150" a="-30" rel="xml/travertine.xml"><img src="collectionType/travertine.jpg" /></div>
          <div id="fig5" cp="225" a="-30" rel="xml/limitededition.xml"><img src="collectionType/limited.jpg" /></div>
        </div>      
      </div>
  </div>

 <!-- Collection By Color -->

<div id="wrapperColor" class="collectionColorWrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="coverflow">        
           <div id="fig1" cp="-150" a="30" rel="xml/natural.xml"><img src="collectionColor/neutral.jpg" /></div>
           <div id="fig2" cp="0" a="0" rel="xml/dark.xml"><img src="collectionColor/dark.jpg" /></div>
           <div id="fig3" cp="150" a="-30" rel="xml/vivid.xml"><img src="collectionColor/vivid.jpg" /></div>
        </div>      
      </div>
  </div>

<div id="popupicon">
<img id="collectionColor" src="images/1.png" style="margin-left:15px" />
<img id="collectionType" src="images/2.png" style="margin:0px 0px 5px 35px" />
</div>


<div id="bottomImgWrapper" class="bottomImgWrapper"></div> 
<div id="bottomImg" class="bottomImg" >
<img src="images/collection.png" class="graavaaImag" id="collection" />
<a href="applications.html"><img src="images/application.png" class="graavaaImag" /></a>
<a href="showrooms.html"><img src="images/showrooms.png"  class="graavaaImag"/></a>
<img src="images/menuLogo.png" class="graavaaIcon" />
</div>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("img#collection").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#popupicon").fadeToggle("slow");     
});

$('#skip').click(function(){
    //localStorage.clear();     
    $("#formContainer").css("display","none");
    $("#bottomImgWrapper").css("display","block");
    $("#bottomImg").css("display","block"); 
    // setting the skip flag
    sessionStorage.setItem('flag','true');              
});

$('.login').submit(function() { 
    var email=$(this).children("#email").val();
    var name=$(this).children("#name").val();                       
    var result=validateEmail($(this).children("#email").val());

    if(result==false){
        //$(this).focus();
        $(".error").html('Invalid Email Address');
        $(".email").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(result==true){
        $(".error").html('');
        localStorage[$("#email").attr('name')] = email;
        localStorage[$("#name").attr('name')] = name;
        alert('Thank You for saving information');
        $("#formContainer").css("display","none");
        $(".bottomImgWrapper").css("display","block");
        $(".bottomImg").css("display","block"); 
        // Dont submit the form in any condition : as it refresh the page  
        return false;
        //return true;  
    }                   

    return false;       
});

$('#collectionType').click(function(){      
        $(".collectionTypeWrapper").css("display","block");
        $(".collectionColorWrapper").css("display","none");
        $("#collectionColor").hide(".collectionTypeWrapper");
        $("#collectionColor").show(".collectionTypeWrapper");

    //$(".collectionTypeWrapper").fadeIn("slow");
    //$(".collectionColorWrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#popupicon").fadeToggle("slow");             
});

$('#collectionColor').click(function(){     
    $(".collectionColorWrapper").css("display","block");
    $(".collectionTypeWrapper").css("display","none");
        //$(".collectionTypeWrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    //$(".collectionColorWrapper").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupicon").fadeToggle("slow");             
});

function validateEmail(txtEmail){
   var filter = /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*?)\s*;?\s*)+/;
    if(filter.test(txtEmail)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {

    function init() {
        //localStorage.clear(); 
        // show the login form if localstorage not persent              

        if(!localStorage["email"]){
            $("#formContainer").css({"display":"block"});
            // hide the bottom images initially
            $("#bottomImgWrapper").css("display","none");
            $("#bottomImg").css("display","none");
        }

        // storing the value into application session
        if(sessionStorage.flag=="true"){
            $("#formContainer").css({"display":"none"});
            $("#bottomImgWrapper").css("display","block");
            $("#bottomImg").css("display","block");
        }

        if(localStorage["email"]){
            $("#formContainer").css("display","none");
            alert('You are already saved as : '+ localStorage["email"]);        
        }
    }

    init();
});

</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coverflow-color.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coverflow-type.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to work because of global variables. The second one overwrites the first one. You also make multiple elements with the same ids. Ids are SINGULAR, you can not have more than one element with the same id.